# Disjoint union of sets $A_i$ indexed by a set $I$ is still a set?

Tags: set-theory

I have a question in set theory considering a disjoint union of sets.

My question is: if we form the following disjoint union $$\bigsqcup_{i \in I} A_i$$ where the $A_i$ are are sets and $I$ is a set as well, then must this disjoint union still be a set? Or can it be a class?

How should I go about proving this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How have you defined the disjoint union?

Comment: What are your axioms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\sf ZF$, the answer is yes. We make particular use of replacement and union here.

Since $I$ is a set, the range of the indexing function is a set, namely $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a set. Now applying the axiom of union, we have that the union over this family is a set indeed.

In weaker theories, this might not be true anymore. For example in $\sf Z$, where the axiom of replacement is not present, this doesn't have to be true. To see why, note that $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of $\sf Z$, but the union over $A_0=V_\omega$, and $A_n=V_{\omega+n+1}\setminus V_{\omega+n}$ for $n>0$, is a disjoint union over a set index, but the result is the entire universe (of the model) which is $V_{\omega+\omega}$.

Comment: Where is the replacement axiom used here?

Comment: Quite literally for having $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ as a set.

Comment: Oh!! I was thinking in terms of specification axiom only