# In the ZF argument for "the union of a family of sets still a set", how to prove that the index mapping for a family of sets is definable?

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to understand the ZF set theory argument for why the following is true:

Let $I$ be any non-empty set, and let $A_i$ be a set for each $i \in I$ (i.e. $A_{i \in I}$ is a family of sets indexed by $I$). Then the object $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ is a set.

I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010383/disjoint-union-of-sets-a-i-indexed-by-a-set-i-is-still-a-set) which provides the argument and I'm trying to understand it. If I understand correctly the argument is simple and uses two axioms from ZF:

- [the axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union): For any set $A$, there is a set $\bigcup A$ which consists of just the elements of the elements of that set $A$
- [the axiom schema of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement): if $F$ is a definable class function, and $A$ is any set, then the image $F[A]$ is also a set.

By the axiom of union, if $\{A_i \mid i \in I\}$ is a set then $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ is a set. So working backwards, it suffices to prove that $\{A_i \mid i \in I\}$ is a set. Defining $F = (i \mapsto A_i)$ we have $F[I] = \{A_i \mid i \in I\}$, so by the axiom schema of replacement it suffices to prove that $i \mapsto A_i$ is a definable class function.

I haven't been able to find the definition of "a definable class function". What is the definition of that? and how do I prove that the index mapping $i \mapsto A_i$ for every indexed family $A_{i \in I}$ is a definable class function?